# Как правильно рассчитать время непрерывной работы, задержку, и время до окончания срока жизни ssl сертификата микросервиса?

Tags: http, ssl, openssl

Есть несколько сервисов, нужно отслеживать их доступность а также срок жизни ssl сертификата.

Конкретно нужно понимать:

1. Сколько сервис проработал без перебоев (время непрерывной работы)
2. Время до окончания срока жизни ssl сертификата
3. Какую задержку дает ssl сертификат при обращении к сервису

Для решения 1 и 2 пункта у меня есть идеи:

1. После каждого неудачного обращения к сервису буду делать дополнительный запрос на проверку доступности http `openssl s_client -connect domain_name:443 -servername domain_name` и смотреть на статус ответа, например:

```
...
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
...
```

или другой код. На основании дополнительно проверки буду делать выводы о том были ли какие-то проблемы с ssl сертификатом или нет.

2. У меня есть доступ к `.pem` файлу каждого сервиса - я могу посмотреть срок его жизни `openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text`

```
...
Validity
      Not Before: Jan 26 20:24:07 2022 GMT
      Not After : Jan 26 20:54:07 2023 GMT
...
```

Подскажите, как вычислить задержку, которую дает ssl сертификат?

Может быть у кого-то есть дополнения к первым двум пунктом?

Comment: У вас тут сразу несколько вопросов в одном. Хотите мониторить состояние МС? Ставьте соответствующие инструменты, у кубера есть liveness пробы - делаете их, настраиваете, добавляете Графану/Кибану и строите графики. Хотите знать сколько времени ушло на установку безопасного соедиения ("SSL")? Например через curl, там есть тайминг [time_appconnect](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME.html) - это оно и есть. Пример: `curl -skL -w %{time_appconnect} https://ya.ru -o /dev/null`. Нужно тоже мониторить? Наверное в Nginx можно настроить лог с выводом таймингов.

Comment: `Время до окончания срока жизни ssl сертификата`. В самом сертификате эта информация есть, вытаскивается через openssl. Также есть инструменты для управления этим (ротация сертификатов), достаточно погуглить. То что вы хотите сделать - похоже на решение на коленке. Лучше найти и освоить существующие инструменты для этого.